# JProfiler: Cannot detect remote JVM

Tags: java, tomcat, java-11, jprofiler

I'm running Tomcat 9 (as user `tomcat`) with OpenJDK 11 on an Ubuntu 18.04 server. I'd like to be able to attach JProfiler 11 to the Tomcat process.

In the past, I've simply used the option to connect to a remote JVM via ssh, and JProfiler locates the process. On this machine, JProfiler never finds the Tomcat process.

I've tried using both the `su` and `sudo` options to switch to the `tomcat` user. I've even enabled login directly as `tomcat`. No matter what, JProfiler cannot locate the JVM process.

I think this is because the `/tmp/hsperfdata_tomcat` folder is empty. I've set `-XX:+UsePerfData` even though it should be enabled by default (trying both `JAVA_OPTS` and `CATALINA_OPTS`) but that didn't solve anything. I've checked the tomcat command line, there is nothing there to disable `UsePerfData`. I've also monitored the folder to see if somehow the `hsperfdata` gets populated but then deleted - the file is never created.

How do I enable profiling with Tomcat 9 on Ubuntu 18.04 with OpenJDK 11?

UPDATE:

Using `jps -l -m` running as `tomcat` returns no output. However running it as `root` *does* list the `tomcat` java process, despite no entry in `/tmp/hsperfdata_tomcat`.

Comment: Could it be a rights issue? Try to temporarily make `/tmp/hsperfdata_tomcat` world writable, restart the profiled JVM and check if that changes anything

Comment: I'll give that a go during the maintenance window. Manually inspecting the permissions, they look good to me. Owned by `tomcat:tomcat`, with write permission to the `tomcat` user.

Comment: I think the problem is that `JProfiler` tries to access the `/tmp` folder via `/proc/pid/root`. Similar to the issue described here, this fails on my system: https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/issues/158

Comment: No, JProfiler does not use /proc/pid. If jps works as root, then jpenable probably also works as root.

Comment: I tried using jpenable as root. It told me it couldn't connect because the target PID was running as a different user.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this exact issue. I was unable to see the JVM started under tomcat user: in jprofiler (11), switching to the tomcat user via sudo showed no JVMs.

It was a permission problem on the uploaded by jprofiler. jpenable is uploaded under my remote home directory to which tomcat has no access to.

Solution was to:

1. ssh to remove node (with same user as what jprofiler will use)
2. `chmod 555 ${HOME}`
3. `chmod 555 -R ${HOME}/.jprofiler11`. Tomcat user needs to access    `${HOME}/.jprofiler11/agent/11082_11.0.2/jprofiler11/bin/jpenable` and jar file in the same dir.
4. Test: `sudo -u tomcat ${HOME}/.jprofiler11/agent/11082_11.0.2/jprofiler11/bin/jpenable`

Then you'll be able to connect your laptop jprofiler to that tomcat user via remote ssh + sudo tomcat.